# How to prevent ptrace anti-debugging in Android?

Tags: android, linux, debugging, reverse-engineering, ptrace

**Introduction:**
I have to reverse engineer an android APK and would like to use tools that rely on `ptrace` for just that.

The APK seems to have implemented an anit-debugging mechanism where it launches two processes. The "helper process" then uses `ptrace` on the "main process". Since `ptrace` can only be used on one process at any given time, it is prevented that other processes can debug the "main" one. An error could look like this:

```
attach: ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, PID): Operation not permitted
```

I am running on a rooted emulator, I am able to use `ptrace` on other processes, killing the "helper process" will result in the "main process" also terminating, the same holds true when using `ptrace` on the "helper process" itself:

```
strace: Process PID attached
wait4(PID,  <unfinished ...>)          = ?
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

**What I already tried:**
Setting the `ptrace scope` to `0` to prevent kernel hardening:

```
echo 0| tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

confirming with

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

yields `0`, the step was successful.

After this didn't work, I tried to use `LD_PRELOAD` to overwrite the existing `ptrace shared object` used by the APK, each of the following commands is ran from the same `adb shell`:

my `ptrace.c`:

```
long ptrace(int request, int pid, void *addr, void *data) {
    return 0;
}
```

compiling:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC ptrace.c -o ptrace.so
```

setting the environment variable:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=./ptrace.so
```

starting the application (I also used `-e` flag, I am not sure if it can be used for environment variables but it also won't do any harm):

```
am start -n the.app.id/the.app.id.MainActivity -e LD_PRELOAD ./ptrace.so
```

Sadly, running:

```
cat /proc/PID/status | grep TracerPid
```

still shows that the `tracer PID` is the "helper process" and not 0. No other process can use `ptrace`on the "main process".

Comment: Not a Reverse Engr or Security Expert, just FYI: https://www.ragingrock.com/AndroidAppRE/reversing_native_libs.html and https://github.com/yellowbyte/analysis-of-anti-analysis/blob/develop/research/hiding_call_to_ptrace/hiding_call_to_ptrace.md

Answer (score 1):

Using [frida with Interception.attach](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#interceptor), what you can do is hook ptrace and always return 0.

Here is the lines of code which hook ptrace and return 0 so you can bypass it:
https://github.com/apkunpacker/FridaScripts/blob/1c2c4538c1b37394c6e2a57a72c9f743bbb75d29/AntiDebug.js#L45. Inside is also a list of way for working around with anti-debug.

For other anti-hook, anti-debug, you can check out the video: [Forging Golden Hammer Against Android App Protections by Georges-Bastien Michel](https://youtu.be/BiMU2CalCqU). The video only contain idea so you have to implement your own from the idea.